# What's the relationship between concentration and refraction rate in a solution?

Tags: optics, phase-diagram

I am supposed to determine the concentration of a solution of ethyl alcohol and cyclohexane by measuring its refraction rate. Now I have some standard sample of the solution at concentrations 10%, 20%, ... , 100% and I measured their refraction rates respectively. I'm now supposed to perform a non-linear fit to the data, but which fitting model should I use? Someone had suggested exponential, and the data look like an exponential growth, but is there a theoretical equation for this?

Comment: It's difficult to comment without seeing the data. Can you pop the data in a Google Docs spreadsheet or something similar and post a link.

Comment: @JohnRennie thanks John, I took care of the data with Eureqa, a software that can heuristically search for the best model!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *theoretical equation* you are looking for is actually referred to as a **model**, which you must hypothesise based on sound reason. The exponential model is one that allows for a rate of change proportional to the current value--for experiments such as objects being decelerated by air resistance (air resistance depends on how fast the object is moving), or amount of radiation emitted by a small radioactive source (amount of radiation depends on how much radioactive material remains), etc. To me this doesn't suit the behaviour of light in media, I would hypothesis a power law instead..of which an example is the inverse square law($r^{-2})$ of light intensity at a distance for example, or inverse square root law ($\rho^{-0.5})$ for terminal velocity due to air density.

> I hypothesise that the speed of light decreases as the density of the
>   medium increases according to some exponent. Paraphrased, the
>   hypothesis suggests a power law relation between solute concentration
>   of a liquid medium and its refractive index.

With concentration(x) and refractive index(n), the power model is $n=Ax^B+D$. This opposed to a linear model $n=Ax+B$ (a.k.a y=mx+c), where $A$ $B$ and $D$ are constants. Note that you can swap n with x here, the polarity of B will flip automatically as a result.

The trick is to transform the nonlinear equation by applying $lg$ to both sides of $n=Ax^B+D$:

$\lg (n)=B \lg(x)+ E$, where $E=\lg(A^BD)$, itself a constant since it involves neither $n$ or $C$.

Clearly plotting $ \lg(n)$ vs $\lg(x)$ produces a straight line with $B$ instantly found by calculating gradient of best fit line, and $E$ also immediately known from the y-intercept of that line. Then it is just a few more steps to obtain A and D.

The exponential form would be $n=n_0 exp(Ax)$, where $n_0$ is the starting refractive index (which increases exponentially with concentration as alternately hypothesized) at zero concentration. To transform this model to linear form, apply natural log to both sides to obtain:

$\lg(n)=Ax + \lg(n_0)$, where $A$ is the gradient and $\lg(n_0)$ is the y-intercept of the graph of $\lg(n)$ vs $x$. Note the difference...

Lastly, both power law and exponential models may seem to be able to fit the data. With few data points this is very possible--and also dangerous (it is tempting to choose exponential model because of ease of manipulation). But the advantage of the power law is that it allows for diminishing growth (exponent <1), whereas exponential model leads to always increasing values for positive arguments. This is another reason in hindsight where I wouldn't use a exponential model, since it predicts boundless growth of refractive index with increasing solute concentration--something which I find will be easily refuted by inspection of your data.

suggestion:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I asked the professor, and she said seeing I'm dealing with a continuous function with finite domain [0,1](mole fraction), and all predictions I have to make fall into that domain, I just need to perform polynomial fitting. And according to knowledge about Taylor series, I should be able to get better fitting by increasing the order, since I'm not going to ask the refraction index for -10% or 200% concentration.

Comment: look at the nonlinear curve first--it will give you a rough idea of what model to use. for example a simple curve with d²y/dx² always >0, you immediately go for exponential model and it would be way simpler than polynomial(which because it requires integer exponents will require many terms just to get a good fit). the only advantage for polynomial form is if the curve is not simple (has a bump in the middle or multiple bumps, like a camel) which is also possible, for example a critical concentration where refraction index is lowest, etc...

Comment: In this case d²y/dx²<0 is always true. And 2nd order polynomial fit gives r²=0.99899, exponential decay gives r²=0.99917, and 5th order polynomial gives r²=0.9999928. I chose exponential decay, which looks simpler and fits better. Thanks for the advice!